# No viable overloaded operator for type smatch

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am using regular expressions to try and find a year in a line of code (4 integers). I am having an error compiling in this line where if they find the four characters I want to return them as integers.

```
if(regex_search(names,match,expr)){
    return stoi(match[index]);
}
```

The index seems to be the problem and this is an unsigned index that is put as a parameter for the function to find the years. Thank you for you help let me know if you need more information.

Here is all the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int find_year(string& names, unsigned index = 0);

int main(){
    ifstream oldretire;
    string names;
    oldretire.open("oldretirement.txt");
    getline(oldretire, names);
    int year = find_year(names);
    cout << year;
}

int find_year(string& names){
    smatch match;
    regex expr("[0-9]{4}");

    if(regex_search(names,match,expr)){
        return stoi(match[index]);
    }
    else
        cout << "No matching argument";
}
```

Comment: Post all the code.

Comment: Ok i posted it all

Comment: Why use `index` if you just need the match value? Try `stoi(match.str())`

Comment: The signature of the find_year() function definition doesn't match that of the declaration of the function.

Comment: You have the arguments to `regex_search` in the wrong order. `names, expr, match`.

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/yYv0di).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems in your code:

- Two `find_year` signatures not match. (This one causes the compile error)
- Missing `return` statement if no match found.

Corrected version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int find_year(string& names, unsigned index = 0);

int main(){
    string names = "foo bar barbar1829foofoo";
    int year = find_year(names);
    cout << year;
    return 0;
}

int find_year(string& names, unsigned index){
    smatch match;
    regex expr("[0-9]{4}");

    if(regex_search(names,match,expr)){
        return stoi(match[index]);
    }
    else
        cout << "No matching argument";
    return -1;
}
```

Hint: better to compile your program with more strict compiling options, like `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra` if you can't find where the problem is next time.